# Install bundler on MacOS with out using sudo?

Tags: macos, rubygems, jekyll, bundler

I'm running MacOS 10.14.1 and can not install Jekyll with out using `sudo` to install bundler. Its here a workaround?

When I run:

`gem install bundler jekyll`

I get:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

With `sudo` everything installs but I keep reading articles about using `sudo` to install gems as being poor practice. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a Jekyll user as well. But, I didn't run into this issue. I believe it's because I use rbenv to manage Ruby, and installed 2.5.3 with it first.

I'd highly recommend checking out [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv). While I do find managing Ruby to be kind of a pain to setup, once you have things set, it works quite well.

One you have a dedicated, non-system-installed Ruby, you won't need sudo. From there, you can also use `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` to really contain your gems into your current project.

Good luck, and hopefully this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can always install to the user directory:

```
% ruby -r rubygems -e 'puts Gem.user_dir'
/Users/muru/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
% gem install bundler --user-install
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/muru/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed bundler-2.0.2
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.0.2
Installing ri documentation for bundler-2.0.2
Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Instead of using the `--user-install` option, you can also set and export `GEM_HOME`:

```
export GEM_HOME=$(ruby -r rubygems -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')
gem install bundler # will install to ~/.gem/ruby/...
```

To use bundler installed this way, as the warning says, you need to add that path to `$PATH`:

```
PATH="$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```